# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lead_x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7

```
def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False

    lead_x_change = display_width/2
    lead_y_change = display_width/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     lead_x_change = block_size
                     lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0

        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0 :
           gameExit = True
```

The unboundlocalerror reads:

> local variable 'lead_x' referenced before assignment.

Please help anyone who knows how to tackle this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should indent all your code by four spaces so that Stack Overflow can properly format it. Your first line did not get formatted as code, and an extra tab was removed from the other lines.

Comment: Just read what it says. "Variable `lead_x` referenced before assignment." So somewhere you have a variable, named `lead_x`, and you reference it (try to get its value) before you assign to it (give it one). Also please search first as this has been explained numerous times on other questions.

Comment: Perhaps you meant for your first set of initializations (`lead_x_change = display_width / 2`...) to actually initialize `lead_x` and `lead_y` instead? The way it's written now, those first two assignments are pointless, anyway, because you immediately reassign 0 to both variables...